# Reload datatable on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I've been refreshing my page on 1 minute intervals in order to keep the data fresh.  I need to stray away from that and finally get the datatable to reload instead of the browser refresh.

Beginning with my $.post:

```
$.post('api/displayQnams.php', function(data)
{
  var table = $('example1').DataTable();
  table.clear();
  table.search('').draw();
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);   
  obj.forEach(function(item)
  {
    table.row.add([item.bkgname, item.quote, item.date, item.urgent]) 
  });
  table.draw();

  setInterval(function()
  {
    table.draw();
    console.log('test'); 
  }, 10000); // 10 second interval
});
```

The above code works fine. DataTable prints to the page with no problem.

Now, above the $.post, I set the DataTable.  I am not sure if this is the best way to set the DataTable, but it does provide the results I need.

```
$(function()
{
  $('#example1').DataTable({
    "dataType": "json", 
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
    "scrollY": 550,
    "scrollX": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "stateSave": true
  });
});
```

There's some more DataTable styles, but I wanted to keep it short.

Going back to my first piece of code, I set the interval for 10 seconds.  I can see the console printing out 'test' every 10 seconds, but the table is not reloading.

What am I missing to get the DataTable to reload every 10 seconds?

### Edit

Here is what the table looks like:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>column1</th>
  <th>column2</th>
  <th>column3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this `row.add` use ajax and define your columns:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/post.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Then in the interval use:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Attempted your suggestion.  I am getting a "TypeError: c is undefined" error, which is pointing to datatables.min.js file.  Thoughts?

Comment: You need table headers. `<thead>`

Comment: <table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling $.post('...') in your setInterval callback function.

Look at your code: inside setInterval callback, you are calling 

`table.draw()
console.log('test')`

So, you are getting your data once and only redrawing the same data over...

EDIT: If you inspect your Network request tab in DevTools, you should note only one ajax request